# 1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")

Tags: mysql, django, ubuntu, vagrant

i'm using xampp and vagrant to run my project but whenever i try to makemigration or run the server i got this error

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
> password: NO)")

here's my connection data

[image]

[image]

and i'm using vagrant to run my project

full error:

[image]
so what's the error?

Comment: Try to add **localhost** instead of **127.0.0.1**

Comment: @AnkitTiwari i did, didn't work also

Answer (score 0):

If you're lauching it from command line, you may have to define env var in that command line (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56458542/preload-the-env-file-from-custom-path))

Comment: already defined

Comment: For answer's with link(s), it is advisable  to highlight the important details or provide a summary regarding what you found in the link you provided. Because time will come that the link will be unavailable/invalid.